# Do javascript promises work using event emitters?

Tags: javascript, promise

I was studying the concept of promises in javascript and the states:pending/resolved/rejected. But I couldn't find much info out there on how the pending state changes to resolved/rejected. Does it happens through event emitters and listeners? If not how does that work?

Comment: Should be explained here: [javascript promises, the event loop, and the job queue](/q/55676922/4642212). Research the _event loop_, and look into the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-objects).

Comment: Listeners/handlers yes, it's the standard observer pattern, but there are no events, and no `EventEmitter` instance for sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I won't do a better job [explaining than the article I used to look into this](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) a little while back but I think the term you're hunting for is `executor`.

> The function passed to new Promise is called the executor. When new Promise is created, the executor runs automatically. It contains the producing code which should eventually produce the result. In terms of the analogy above: the executor is the “singer”.

Its arguments resolve and reject are callbacks provided by JavaScript itself. Our code is only inside the executor.

When the executor obtains the result, be it soon or late, doesn’t matter, it should call one of these callbacks:

resolve(value) — if the job is finished successfully, with result value.
reject(error) — if an error has occurred, error is the error object.
So to summarize: the executor runs automatically and attempts to perform a job. When it is finished with the attempt, it calls resolve if it was successful or reject if there was an error.